# iPhone - I've changed the XIB FileOwner, but it keeps hitting methods in the original File Owner

Tags: iphone, interface, xib, builder, viewcontroller

So...

1. I have a HomeViewController, with an IBAction DoStuff.
2. I have a XIB that has a File Owner of HomeViewController, which contains
   button that correctly calls DoStuff;
3. Then created a NewViewController, copying the DoStuff method into it.
4. Within the XIB, I then updated the Class of the File Owner to
   NewViewController, and deleted and re-added the action to the button
   for DoStuff.

BUT... the button is still calling DoStuff from HomeViewController.

Is there somewhere else I need to remove this reference??

Thanks very much,

R

Comment: Recheck `File's Owner` and that you are loading from a right nib file

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are loading the nib file from the right controller? note that "File's Owner" is just a placeholder in the nib file and it must have been created in code; besides the "class name" in File's Owner is only needed by IB to provide the references to its IBAction and IBOutlet but you need to ensure that you're loading it in code correctly.

So if in the old code you had something like:

```
HomeViewController *myController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

you must change the current code as:

```
NewViewController *myController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
```

in this case you will keep loading the same nib file but all objects will be unarchived and assigned to the right file owner which is the one specified in the code.

Please check this point, if it's not working then post your code.